# Customize notification for incoming Hangouts message - Android

Tags: android, notifications, customization, google-hangouts

I just started work on android project for myself. I´d like to create app for customize notification from a couple of applications, like hangouts or gmail. I already know how to work with `android.app.Notification` and `android.app.NotificationManager`. But I don´t know how to bind up it with hangouts notifications. Is there any API for hangouts in Android? How do I set up my own notification (LED, sound, ..)?